Can there be decoherence of quantum fluctuations in Minkowski spacetime?
I was reading a paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.0808) on whether observers (like Boltzmann Brains) arising from vacuum fluctuations could occur in a Minkowski vacuum. I had a a question on this:
The authors indicated that even in a Minkowski vacuum, there may be indeed some fluctuations that would give rise to a Boltzmann brain. However, these would not decohere and therefore could be argued to be "non-real" so for an observer looking at the entire Minkowski vacuum these would be non-existent. However, for a local observer with a measuring apparatus, they could make them decohere.
Then I asked one of the authors about this and its consequences, but he told me that

An actual measuring apparatus could certainly find the brain in a region
of (what had formerly been) the vacuum.  Then there will be no
disagreement: this brain really exists.  But if such an apparatus is
present, we would not be in the vacuum.

i.e. that in any case, there would not be any obsrerver in the vacuum.
But why wouldn't there be any observers in the vacuum? Is it impossible? Or is it a matter of definition (that in a perfect Minkowsmi vacuum there would not be observers by definition)?
In the latter case, then, would a universe that is expanding linearly (i.e. without a cosmological constant), and therefore, asymptotically approaches to a Minkowski vacuum, could still have local observers that could decohere these fluctuations?

The outcome of an experiment on a quantum system in general depends on what happens to all of its possible states because of interference, see Section 2 of this paper for an example:
https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9911150
An interfering system can't be understood in terms of it storing a single value and so it isn't really suitable for storing information. When information is copied out of an interfering system interference is suppressed, an effect called decoherence:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06282
Decoherence requires that the existence of independent systems that aren't undergoing the same interference process as the system being decohered. Those systems may sometimes be subsystems of a larger system but records of the information thus copied must continue to exist even if it is in some scrambled form in a thermal reservoir or whatever.
The vacuum is just the ground state of a bunch of quantum fields. You could imagine that different subsystems of the quantum field decohere one another in the ground state or something like that:
https://arxiv.org/abs/0910.5733
But this is just an untested model. The situation you're describing is wildly different from anything that has been observed or tested. There is no particular reason to think we have a good handle on it and the paper you refer to ignores problems in our understanding of the vacuum such as the apparent lack of gravitational effects from the large amount of energy that is allegedly present in the vacuum:
https://pubs.aip.org/aapt/ajp/article-abstract/63/7/620/593767/Vacuum-catastrophe-An-elementary-exposition-of-the
The paper itself hints at this lack of understanding by admitting that they don't know what the relevant measure is for getting probabilities. If they understood the physics then they would know the relevant measure.
Another problem is that a human brain stores information about results of past computations in the brain, such as memories and the warm wet environment in the brain is another source of decoherence:
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9907009
So parts of the human brain decohere other parts. So if a Boltzmann brain arose in the vacuum its subsystems would already be decoherent so the authors don't understand decoherence very well.
Overall this paper isn't very good: it is highly speculative in the bad sense of not paying attention to whether their ideas are well motivated theoretically or can be experimentally tested.

I think that the root of the question for me with this paper is: Can there be quantum fluctuations that give rise to macroscopic objects (like e.g. an apple or a galaxy) in Minkowski spacetime without a cosmological constant (even if thr fluctuations would be extremely unlikely, but not impossible)? @alanf
